# Causative + Potential and the verb 合わせる

Tags: verbs, potential-form, causation

[image]

What exactly is the use of 合わせる　here? Causative + potential?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this verb.  *(Note that I'm keeping the list of senses deliberately short for the sake of simplicity.)*

合わせる is analyzable as the causative of 合う.

- 合【あ】う: to come together, to happen together, to do together
- 合【あ】わせる: to cause to come, happen, or do together

It is also regarded by modern Japanese resources as a verb unto itself.

- 合【あ】わせる: to put together, to combine things (transitive)

In this second sense, we get the natural passive of that:

- 合【あ】わせられる: to be put together, to be combined

Passives can also be used to express potential.  Whether or not to translate a passive verb as potential in English comes down to the context of the source and what you want to emphasize.

Comment: This 合わせられる is definitely potential ("I *can* adjust anything (to fit your needs)").